# Best practice to document a complex nested dictionary parameter in a Python docstring?

Tags: python, docstring

for a project I am working on, I have written a function that creates multiple animations with matplotlib. The problem is, the function accepts a fairly complex and (if I'm being completely honest) unintuitive nested dictionary as its main parameter. Currently, the dictionary has the following format:

```
dictionary = {`int` : {keyword_argument : {sub_keyword_argument : boolean,
                                           sub_keyword_argument : boolean},
                       keyword_argument : function object,
                       keyword_argument : tuple containing arguments for the above function object}
```

So definitely not the easiest parameter to work with. As such, I feel the easiest way to document this in a function docstring is to use a table but as far as I can tell, there is no in built way to create a table inside a Python docstring. I'm just wondering what would be the best way to document this parameter in a docstring that explains how it all works.

I've also considered just separating the parameter into three separate dictionary arguments where the keys of each dictionary argument is `int`. However, the way the function works, each dictionary would have to have the same keys anyways so I though I might as well put them all into one big dictionary. To be honest, I'm actually not sure which would be the best practice either.

Answer (score 2):

Python docstrings can have any format you like.

However, [the standard tools for Python documentations](https://pypi.org/project/Sphinx/) support [reStructuredText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText), which support multiple [syntaxes for tables](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#tables), e.g.:

```
=====  =====  =======
A      B      A and B
=====  =====  =======
False  False  False
True   False  False
False  True   False
True   True   True
=====  =====  =======
```

However, if this is as unfriendly as you think, you may want to consider splitting this single parameter into multiple simpler parameters.